# Correct way to load translated data Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, localization, laravel-localization

I am building my first multilingual Laravel website.

For the translations i am using this package: [laravel-localization](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization).

In my database i have the columns set up like this:

- title (english title)
- title_nl (dutch title)
- title_fr (french title)

I have read the laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/localization) on Localization and set up my error messages this way. But now i'm confused on how to correctly show the different languages for my views.

Should i do something like this:

```
@if( LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale() == 'nl')
<p>{{$post->title_nl}}</p>

@elseif(LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale() == 'fr' )
 <p>{{$post->title_fr}}</p>

@else
  <p>{{$post->title}}</p>
 @endif
```

This seems extremely messy and not the correct way to handle this, because expanding this would be a nightmare.

Or do i need to use the build in localization functions for this like so:

```
{{ trans('post.title') }}
```

Or does that defeat the purpose of the package i am using?

Comment: You can use only `{{ trans('post.title') }}` , you dont need to add lang suffixes. Only detect lang `@if( LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale() == 'nl')` etc.

Comment: @mcklayin so that means i have to load my model in my post.php file for each language ? and loop trough the fields in the language file itself?

Answer (score 1):

Using key value pair of multidimensional arrays

Add translations in DB and get load in array when required

```
$language['word_key']="word";
```

keep word key in your code as it is just load translations in array based on language

in DB create 2 tables 1 for keywords which is primary table and other for translations which have foreign key of keywords table

Write a language class that can provide you array of key => value pair to use in code

example in simple php

```
echo $language['kw_hi'];
```

if you run with english it prints "Hi" in French "Salut"
code remains same just content changes

```
{!! Form::label($dictionary['apo_add_subject'], $dictionary['apo_add_subject']) !!}
```

Above the dictionary has keyword apo_add_subject . i have created a table with keywords id,keyword_name  and second table translations id , kw_id , language , translation then based on language and module i am loading it in array using middle were and then passing to view  where code written above will used .

Just load different values in array keeping same keywords

Comment: I don't really understand this solution fully. Can you make an example with the example i gave in my opening post?